# Icons on Quick Launch show as blank pages - Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, icons, quicklaunch

I know this has been asked before, but no answer has worked for me.  I rebuilt the icon cache two or three times and the blank pages keep coming back every time I reboot.  If I click on the program icon, the correct icon returns, only to go to a blank page icon after a reboot. It's not all icons either, just the Office icons, Explorer, and Windows Live Mail icons. Can anyone help with this?  This is a brand new Dell computer and this has happened since day 1.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

FIXED - If rebuilding your icon cache does not fix your problem, maybe this will.

1. Right-click on the blank page icon in your quick launch area and go to "Properties".
2. On the "Short Cut" tab, select "Change Icon".
3. Select the "Browse" button and browse to the executable of that program, probably in Programs.  Example- Internet Explorer - browse to Program Files (x86), Internet Explorer, then click on iexplorer.exe and select open. A whole new set of icons to choose from will open.
4. Select the icon you want. Click OK, then Apply.

The problem appears to be in the properties of your shortcut.  "Target" and "Start in" may be blank or have a strange string as compared to the quick launch programs with icons that work - they point to their respective executables.

Hope this helps!